# No .key file from openssl self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl

I generated a self-signed SSL cert on Debian with openssl, and installed the certificate in Windows, so it loads in Chrome okay.

However, I have no .key file in /etc/ssl/certs/

I only have a .pem file (which is used in lighttpd.conf)

Is there anything wrong with this? What does the .key file do, and should I go through openssl again to make a .key file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your .pem file has lines that say `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` then your key is in that combined .pem file and that is just fine.

Comment: you're right. I used a different website to get the command the second time, so it must have had an option/switch omitted. thanks